# Is there any limit on number of events of a iCal subscription feed in Google Calendar?

Tags: icalendar

This was the problem we encountered.

- This is a [link](https://feed2-archive-atom.orangehrm.com/calendar_small.ics) to a small calendar we have created. When we add this to the Google Calendar (Add other calendars -> From URL), all events are shown.
- However, the issue arises when we attempt to get a calendar with many events.
- There are 18000 iCalendar events at this URL. but no events were
  shown when we add [this link](https://feed2-archive-atom.orangehrm.com/calendar.ics) to the Google Calendar.

I searched for if there is any exact limit to the number of events. Google calendar has a limitation mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/45654#zippy=%2Cical-file-file-ends-with-ics) that is up to 1MB file size for uploading as an ICS file. But I was unable to see any limits for calendars that are subscribed from a URL. Is there a limit on how many events we can fetch? If not, could you please tell me if our API has any issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the following response and troubleshooting steps from the Outlook support team.

*The web browser that you are using also plays a role in handling your email account so it would help if we could optimize the web browser that you are using by clearing its cache and cookies.
Reset Browser.*

1. *Open Internet Explorer (Gear icon > Internet Option > Advance > Reset)*
2. *Open Google Chrome (Ellipsis > Settings > Show Advance Settings > Reset)*
3. *For Mozilla Firefox try searching in [www.bing.com](http://www.bing.com/) (How to reset Firefox browser)*

*You also can try below mentioned link to logout from [outlook.com](http://outlook.com/). Simply click on the link, it will logout and will redirect on sign in screen: https://login.live.com/logout.srf*

*Please use any different browser you regularly uses. Then please observe the behavior for next 24-48 hours.*

*Outlook.com is a web based email access platform and some time because of the browsers issues/glitch we might faces the issues.*

After doing the suggested troubleshooting steps, in certain cases, previously unseen events were shown. However, not all of the events were shown.